# Why is variable initialisation redundant?

Tags: java

I've solved a 3*N + 1 problem (100) on UVa Online Judge but here's one thing that I don't understand, but it has something to do with Java, I guess, not with the algorithm itself. So here's the code:

```
private static int maxCycleLength(int lo, int hi) {
        maxLength = 0;
        int n = 0;
        int length = 0;

    for (int i = lo; i <= hi; i++) {
        // It's the first time we're computing the cycle length for n
        if (lengths[i] == 0) {
            n = i;
            length = 1;
            while (n != 1) {
                if ((n % 2) == 0) {
                    n = n >> 1;
                    length++;
                }
                else {
                    n = 3 * n + 1;
                    n = n >> 1;
                    length += 2;
                }
            }
            lengths[i] = length;
        }
        // Otherwise we just look it up
        else
            length = lengths[i];

        // Check if the current cycle length is the maximum
        if (length > maxLength)
            maxLength = length;
    }
    return maxLength;
```

**What I don't understand:** My IDE (IDEA) tells me that in this piece of code the initialisation of variables `n` and `length`is redundant, however, `maxLength` must be initialised and if I don't do it, it does not compile.

Why so? How is `maxLength` different here from `n` and `length`?

Comment: BTW: with the same efficiency once could place `int length;` just after `for {` and `int n  : i;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On all code paths, you initialize `n` and `length` before you ever try and read a value from them. Regardless of what happens, the value you assign to them initially will not be used, since you'll overwrite it with something else before you need it.

`maxLength` though gets read from before you assign a new value to it, when you do the `length > maxLength` comparison, or in the `return`, if the `for` loop is skipped. Since it won't have a value on the first pass, you need to give it a starting value to use.

Answer (score 1):

`maxLength` is different because its value is used outside the for loop. If the for loop is never entered, `maxLength` will never be initialized (if you remove the initialization at the start), so the return statement becomes invalid.

The other two variables (`n` and `length`) are guaranteed to be assigned before they are accessed, even after removing the initial initializations. They are not accessed outside the for loop, and inside the for loop, both the `if` and `else` clauses start by initializing `length`. `n` is initialized only by the `if` cluase, but it's only accessed within that clause.